# prgress bar when proccessing update application VB NET

Tags: vb.net

How do you show a progress bar when an application is updating?

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            Dim AD As ApplicationDeployment = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment
            'how to show progress bar in this section
            AD.Update()
```

`MessageBox.Show("The application has been upgraded, and will now restart.")
            Application.Restart()
        Catch dde As DeploymentDownloadException
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot install the latest version of the application. " & ControlChars.Lf & ControlChars.Lf & "Please check your network connection, or try again later.")
            Return
        End Try
    End Sub`

Comment: start by adding a progressbar on the form.

Comment: And then..? Can you give me an example..? Thanks for ur respon..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this site. [system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.aspx) Notice the events section?  Follow the examples in there for the various events.